# Error when attempting to create new model

Tags: clarifai

This is the error: Something went wrong. Your request was blocked. Missing feature flags: [TrainingDeepTraining].

Answer (score 0):

Could you please send an email to support@clarifai.com with your account email and any error messages you are getting with their req_id and we can check for you what is going on.

Best Regards,

Clarifai Support

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because free users do not have access to create "Visual Classifier/Detector/Embed" models.  This should be prevented by the front end but currently is not (appears to be a bug).